# QReport making a grid with 24 cells in a 3x8 layout

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, quickreports

I'm using QuickReport 5 in Delphi 2007.
I want to make a grid layout on A4 paper like so:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  | 2   | 3   |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  4  | 5   | 6   |
...
| 22  | 23  | 24  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

I only have detail bands, I need this to print address stickers in a Delphi application, with a different address on each sticker.
How do I do this in QuickReport?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need that order? If you can increment vertically instead of horizontally, this is actually quite simple in QR.

Comment: @Ken White, I missed the whole column thing, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set columns in your Quickreport.
Double click on the Quickreport and set the columns to 3.
This will set the columns like so:

```
1    9    17   
2   10    18 
3   11    19
4   12    20
5   13    21
6   14    22
7   15    23
8   16    24
```

If you want the columns to run like in your question you need to do some creative sorting in the query that feeds the report.

`Order by rank div 24, if(rank mod 8 = 0,8,rank mod 8), rank`

This will make things come out with 1,2,3 in the first row and 456 in the seconds etc.